# Inductor Fed VR Tube

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, vacuum-tube

Would it be beneficial to feed a voltage regulator tube with an inductor (as in the following pic)?

[image: Inductor Fed VR Tube]

I'm thinking that a 50vdc air-gaped reed relay coil would do the trick. They measure about 1.9k each (@ 2mH), so they should be able to handle around 25mA. Perhaps this would filter some of the power line RF which the tube is unable to regulate.

Would there be any potential issues?

Would this actually be useful at all, or just a fancy resistor substitute?

Comment: What's the application?

Comment: Should work. Impedance with struck tube will be lowish. Adding a capacitor as well may be useful.

Comment: Hi Andy, the VR tube would power a thyratron oscillator. I'm just wanting the signal to be as clean as possible without using solid-state components.

Comment: Thanks Russell, I do plan to add a .047uF cap to the tube.

Comment: Any more input out there from anyone?

Comment: Would a flyback diode be in order? So as to protect switches in the regulated load, or regulation sag.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your relay coil proposal BUT if your power source is a 50Hz transformer single phase full wave rectifier then most of the power supply noise will be

100 or 120 HZ so millihenries wont do it   in fact you want henries to achieve anything In the old days before I was born high inductance filter chokes were common but nowdays capacitors are generaly much smaller cheaper and easier to find

Comment: high inductance chokes can still be bought from some manufacturers, they are usually used in tube amps with tube rectifiers.